# Keeping a terminal window open after running script from crontab

Tags: shell, scripting, terminal, cron

I have this script

```
#!/bin/sh
curl -4 http://wttr.in/Colorado\ Springs
```

that I want to automatically execute each morning. I have my crontab entry as

```
* 7 * * * (path to script)
```

But either the script doesnt run, or it runs and then immediately closes the shell. I know that my cronjobs are running as I have other scripts for backups that run on an hourly basis but cant figure out what detail I am missing here. I found one suggestion to include $SHELL in the script but that made no difference. Any suggestions?

Comment: cron jobs run in the background without a terminal, so there wouldn't be a window to keep open in the first place. and you couldn't have a cron job prompt for input (e.g. "press any key to continue...") since there'd be nowhere to get the input from, let alone display the prompt.

Comment: So then there wouldnt be any way to just get a window to stay open and display the response of   curl -4 http://wttr.in/Colorado\ Springs   automatically at a certain time? Perhaps something other than a cron job?

Comment: no. but cron generally emails the output of the job to the account the job's running as.

Comment: Ok. That make sense. I was thinking maybe something like this in the script but that doesn't seem to work either. 
    open -a Terminal --command=curl -4 http://wttr.in/Colorado\ Springs -H

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I have to keep the terminal open I would `exec bash` as my last command. I do that when I write installer script which would open terminal; do the job and get lost after that. But if there is an error then I want the terminal to stay there so that I can read the error.

exec is used to replace the current program with argument which we provide to exec.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know what are you trying to achieve with this call in your crontab. Do you want to see the weather report on your terminal? Do you want to save the weather report in the file? Get it in your emails?

If you do no redirections, you'll get the report in your mail.

If you want to have it in a file, just do:

```
curl wttr.in/Colorado+Springs > file
```

If you want to have it on you terminals do

```
curl wttr.in/Colorado+Springs | wall
```

Please note that you don't need -4, http:// and you can replace \space with +.

(DISCLAIMER: I'm the author of wttr.in)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I am going about it wrong but I'm just trying to find a way to have it automatically pop up in terminal each morning so it's there when I get up and check my computer. I'm pretty amateur but I knew cron was used to schedule jobs so I figured that would be the route to go. Perhaps there is something else more appropriate?

Comment: @JakeStewart: Cron is ok, the only question, how it should look like, the popup?